# Attaching components after gltf.InstantiateMainScene through glTFast in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gltf

I'm loading and instantiating a glTF model using glTFast in Unity. After I load and instantiate the model successfully in runtime, I need to attach a component to the instantiated `GameObject` through the `gameObject.AddComponent<>()` method.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI;

public class ObjectManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    //This runs first
    void OnEnable()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnEnable called");
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    //this runs second
    async void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnSceneLoaded: " + scene.name);

        var gltf = new GLTFast.GltfImport();

        var success = await gltf.Load("file://Assets/Models/lounger_armchair/scene.gltf");

        if (success)
        {

            // Instantiate the glTF's main scene
            gltf.InstantiateMainScene(new GameObject("PlacedModel").transform);

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Loading glTF failed!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! You script is of course `c#`

Comment: I don't know that library but in general you can't use most of the Unity API asynchronous but would have to make sure it ends up in the main thread

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest works as expected as I understand you want to attach a component to the `PlacedModel` object.

You could simply store it beforehand and do

```
var placedModel = new GameObject("PlacedModel").transform;
if(gltf.InstantiateMainScene(placedModel))
{
    placedModel.gameObject.AddComponent<SomeComponent>();
}
else
{
    Debug.LogError("Instantiating glTF failed!");
    Destroy (placedModel);
}
```

Or the same if you rather want to attach the component to the first child of that object

```
var placedModel = new GameObject("PlacedModel").transform;
if(gltf.InstantiateMainScene(placedModel))
{
    placedModel.GetChild(0).gameObject.AddComponent<SomeComponent>();
}
else
{
    Debug.LogError("Instantiating glTF failed!");
    Destroy (placedModel);
}
```